# What is the smallest positive integer $k$ such that $a^{8k} = e$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $a$ be an element of order 12 in a group G.

$a^{12}=e$. Of course also $a^{12\ell}=e^\ell=e$.

I feel like the answer is 3.

because the smallest multiple of 8 and 12 is 24.

So 8+8+8=24

cause then the exponent theorem is: $(a^m)^n = a^{mn}$

$(a^8)^3=a^{3(8)}=a^{24}$

Comment: Depends on the group.

Comment: @Randall Sorry I forgot to add the group, fixed that now.

Comment: What's the smallest multiple of $8$ that is also a multiple of $12$?

Comment: This question is really very easy. I would recommend that you think some more about it before asking for help.

Comment: @Joffan the smallest multiple is 24.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reminder of the definition may help:

[Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)):

> The order, sometimes period, of an element $a$ of a group is the smallest positive integer $m$ such that $a^m = e$, where $e$ denotes the identity element of the group

So you know in your case that $a^{12}=e$. Of course also $a^{12\ell}=e^\ell=e$.

Comment: $a^{12}=e$. Of course also $a^{12\ell}=e^\ell=e$. 

I feel like the answer is 3. 

because the smallest multiple of 8 and 12 is 24.

So 8+8+8=24

cause then the exponent theorem is: $(a^m)^n = a^{mn}$

$(a^8)^3=a^{3(8)}=a^{24}$

Comment: Looks like you got it.

Comment: Yay! thank you much!!! :D

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* $a^n = e$ iff $n$ is a multiple of $12$. So the question is: what is the smallest $k$ such that $8k$ is a multiple of $12$?